# JAXB Compilation issue -'ArrayOfstring' is already defined

Tags: maven, xsd, jaxb, wsdl, xjc

I'm getting this error when I run "mvn clean install"

Thrown by JAXB: 
[ERROR] Thrown by JAXB: 'ArrayOfstring' is already defined 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Thrown by JAXB: (related to above error) the first definition appears here 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Thrown by JAXB: 'ArrayOfstring' is already defined

ArrayOfString appears multiple times in multiple XSD files using the same namespace.

wsdl0:

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"> 
    <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfstring">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="string" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="ArrayOfstring" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfstring"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

wsdl1:

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfstring">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="string" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="ArrayOfstring" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfstring"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

How would I resolve this? I'm assuming I would have to use an external bindings file...Thanks!

Sam

Answer (score 0):

I would generate for each wsdl the classes in a different package and then you will not have any clashes. This can be achieved using binding files:

https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Configure-Target-Packages-in-Binding-Files as you assumed.